# Github workflow - error when executing py script. But script works locally

Tags: python, github, github-actions

I created the following github repository: https://github.com/kmeans27/ball-classification
The code is used to classify batches of images of balls within a folder and classify the balls according to their type and store it in a csv file.

I am new in deploying applications, the code works fine locally. So I guess I missed on mentioning some libraries in the requirements.txt file.

When running the workflow in github actions the following error message is shown:

```
Run python3 batch_predict.py
2023-02-28 13:34:41.767390: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 AVX512F FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-02-28 13:34:41.897448: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.16/x64/lib
2023-02-28 13:34:41.897476: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2023-02-28 13:34:42.724127: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.16/x64/lib
2023-02-28 13:34:42.724212: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.16/x64/lib
2023-02-28 13:34:42.724220: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/work/ball-classification/ball-classification/batch_predict.py", line 4, in <module>
    from flask_app import classify_image
  File "/home/runner/work/ball-classification/ball-classification/flask_app.py", line 13, in <module>
    model = load_model('ball_classifier.h5')
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.16/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.16/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 567, in __init__
    fid = make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, fcpl, swmr=swmr)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.16/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 231, in make_fid
    fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/h5f.pyx", line 106, in h5py.h5f.open
OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

The error summary IMO:

1.TensorFlow is unable to load some dynamic libraries related to CUDA and TensorRT.

2.The batch_predict.py script is failing to import the classify_image function from flask_app.py.

3.The load_model function from Keras is unable to open the HDF5 file ball_classifier.h5.

I am not sure why error 2. and 3. are showing up. Everything is working fine locally. Both files exist and are in the same directory. For the first error message I have literally no clue.

Thank you for your valuable time firends!

Comment: There is a [Github Action](https://github.com/Jimver/cuda-toolkit) to install CUDA. Have you tried it?

Comment: Thank you @Tranbi for your reply, I tried installing the CUDA using the .yml file. But i still get the same errors. I think there is an error on git lfs process. Because the script was not able to load the model.

Answer (score 0):

error was that i did not include lfs = true in the .yml file